# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name for ManyToOne association

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernateexception

Sorry to ask this question. Many may say that there are lots of answers but My bad luck none of those worked for me.

Here is the Entity Class:
TIMELINE ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIMELINE")
public class Timeline extends ChronosEntity implements HasIdAndDomain, HasIdAndOwnerUser {
private Long id;
private String name;
private int nofAsgSlotsPerDay;
private Long ownerUserId;
private User owner;
private Long domainId;
private Domain domain;

@Id
@Column(name = "TIMELINE_ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(15)")
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "TIMELINE_NAME", unique = true)
@NotNull
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "NOF_ASG_SLOTS_PER_DAY")
public int getNofAsgSlotsPerDay() {
    return nofAsgSlotsPerDay;
}

public void setNofAsgSlotsPerDay(int nofAsgSlotsPerDay) {
    this.nofAsgSlotsPerDay = nofAsgSlotsPerDay;
}

@Column(name = "OWNER_USER_ID")
public Long getOwnerUserId() {
    return ownerUserId;
}

public void setOwnerUserId(Long ownerUserId) {
    this.ownerUserId = ownerUserId;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

@Column(name = "DOMAIN_ID")
public Long getDomainId() {
    return domainId;
}

public void setDomainId(Long domainId) {
    this.domainId = domainId;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DOMAIN_ID", referencedColumnName = "DOMAIN_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Domain getDomain() {
    return domain;
}

public void setDomain(Domain domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
}
}
```

One this to mention is that I am not using bi-directional association.
Domain entity has the primary key "DOMAIN_ID".

Now the error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: TIMELINE_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(DOMAIN) and its related supertables and secondary tables
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:829)
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:242)
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1757)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1700)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1628)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:276)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:770)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:797)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance \n
**Edit-1**: Domain Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOMAIN")
public class Domain extends ChronosEntity implements HasId, HasIdAndOwnerUser {
@Id
@Column(name = "DOMAIN_ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(15)")
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "DOMAIN_NAME", unique = true)
@NotNull
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "OWNER_USER_ID")
public Long getOwnerUserId() {
    return ownerUserId;
}

public void setOwnerUserId(Long ownerUserId) {
    this.ownerUserId = ownerUserId;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT(15)")
public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreationTimestamp
public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}
}
```

**Edit-2**: Chronos entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ChronosEntity {
private Long version;
private Long transactionId;

@Version
@Column(name="VERSION", columnDefinition="BIGINT(15)")
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Column(name="TRANSACTION_ID", columnDefinition="BIGINT(15)")
public Long getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
}
public void setTransactionId(Long transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}
}
```

**Annotation** from javax.persistence package.

Comment: Please publish DOMAIN entity as well.

Comment: There could a problem with joins. Could you post the 2 classes instead of only a part of one class?

Comment: Check the updated question.

Comment: I can not see the "both ways" connection between classes. I think there should be something like @OneToMany private TIMELINE ENTITY tEntity; Do you have it?

Comment: @Lipu Can you post ChronosEntity?

Comment: @NickJI ChronosEntity is just a mapped super class holding the version of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You should also create the opposite `@OneToMany` association in the DOMAIN object. You can leave it a private field if you don't want the bi-directional association.

Add this to Domain class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="domain")
private List<TimeLine> timelines =  new ArrayList<>();
```

According to the way you described the problem you do have bi-directional association, you just don't want things to be changed on the Timeline object when working on a Domain object so just make sure `timelines` is private and has no getter/setter. This will solve the problem and still keep the desired behavior.

Comment: I did tried that also but still no luck. I also tried with getter and setter still no luck. :(

Comment: I noticed you haven't published the class definition of both classes. Do you have some annotations on the classes?